# Help with integral $\int_{-1}^6\frac{dx}{\sqrt{9+16x^2}}$

Tags: calculus

$$\int_{-1}^6\frac{dx}{\sqrt{9+16x^2}}$$

What identities should I be using here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{9+16x^2}}=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{4x}{3}\right)^2}}$$

and then trying the substitution

$$\frac{4}{3}x=\sinh u\Longrightarrow dx=\frac{3}{4}\cosh u\,du \ldots$$

Comment: That helps a lot more. Just a quick question, where do you get (4x/3)^2 from?

Comment: When I took $\,9\,$ out of the root as to have $\,\sqrt{1+A^2}\,$ , which is a expression that reminds of hyperbolic functions because of $\,\cosh^2x-\sinh^2x=1\,$

Comment: I see what you did but Im still a little stuck. I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I think of it this way. If we had $16x^2=9u^2$, we would get a common $9$ which comes out as a $3$. So we want $4x=3u$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\frac{d}{dx}(sinh^{-1}(x))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$. Now what are the suitables substitutions